# Node aws-sdk: Cannot find module "lodash/object/assign"

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have been reading that aws-sdk uses an ancient version of XMLBuilder in https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/pull/1143,

but I am unsure of what solution to implement in order to work around this.  What can I do to use a more modern version of XMLBuilder?

aws-sdk's packaged version is   "xmlbuilder": "2.6.2", which uses a version of lodash that is inconsistent with the rest of my up-to-date modules.